# Unity - Affect only clicked GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, and I tried to create a prefab for a tile in a game. So whenever a user clicks the tile it should change its sprite. The problem is that all the copies (instances) in my game are changing their sprite.

This is what I tried:

```
   void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject gameObject = this.gameObject;
            SpriteRenderer renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/red");
            renderer.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: So it looks you are not getting clicked sprite, you change all gameobjects sprites when you click mouse button which have this script, you must get clicked tile then only change this tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are detecting if the mouse button is pressed, not if it's pressed **over** the given tile.

There are several ways to do it, but I would say the standard way is to:

1. Attach a **Collider** to the GameObject
2. Implement [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
     GameObject gameObject = this.gameObject;
     SpriteRenderer renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
     Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/red");
     renderer.sprite = sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like akin said you are changing all sprites on a mouse click, you can raycast to your objects and check if they are hit then change it

Run this part on a script attached to your player or camera

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, 100.0f)) {
if (hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<yourscript>()) {    
hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<yourscript>().ChangeSprite();
        }
}
}
```

attach to tile game objects

```
public class yourscript : MonoBehaviour

{

public void ChangeSprite() {
            SpriteRenderer renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/red");
            renderer.sprite = sprite;
}

}
```